# Selenium WebDriver Big Project File Size

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Whenever I use the selenium libraries in one of my projects, it will kick up the file size to ~ 23 MB. (I have added all .jars to the build path).

[Selenium downloads](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)

This is annoying to deal with since everything takes much longer.

Is there a way to make it light-weight? How can it be that huge because of source codes? Am I doing something wrong? I never passed even 1 MB before with other external libraries and projects.

Comment: What file size goes up to 23mb and what takes longer?

Comment: The file size of the whole project / exported .jar file goes up to 23,X MB. It takes longer to export, upload and download (unneccessarily?)